# How to create a function that delays call to given function?

Tags: ramda.js

Using `ramda`, I'm trying to find (or build) a very trivial operator that expects a function and returns a function that asks for its arguments before returning a new function that makes the actual call. You can think of this as "delaying" the invocation. As pointed out by replies below, this is usually call a `thunk`.

Essentially,

```
const wrap = fn => (...args) => () => fn(...args);

const sayHiWorld = wrap(console.log)('hi', 'world');
sayHiWorld();
// -> 'hi world'
```

Partial application won't work in my case because args are actually not known at moment of definition. Closest I got was by using `R.useWith` - but that restricts the number of arguments.

Any ideas?

Comment: This worked for me: `const sayHi = x => \`hi ${x}\`; const sayHiWorld = partial(sayHi, ['world']); sayHiWorld();`

Comment: Thanks for the example. Unfortunately, as explained in the question, that would not work for my use case because the actual arguments are unknown at creation time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a little confused.  It looks as though you have a perfectly good version here in your `wrap`.  Are you expecting that Ramda must already have that?  Do you want a version of it written with Ramda?

What you want to create with a call to this function is often known as a **[`thunk`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk)**, and I've sometimes seen such a function called `thunkify`.  But `wrap` is fine too.

You might see the discussion **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49202199/1243641)** too.

Comment: Thanks for both the answer and the link to the discussion. And for the reminder about the concept of `thunk`s. That's certainly what this is. Though I was expecting an answer along the lines of "but you have a working solution right there", my question was more towards "does such operator exist in Ramda, so I don't have to write it myself". Last time I checked, neither `ramda` nor `ramda-adjunct` offer it and being both so trivial and useful led me believe I was missing something here.

Comment: Ramda itself definitely doesn't offer it.  If you wanted to create a PR for such a functions, it would get a hearing from the Ramda team.

Comment: PR approved!  Thank you for your contribution.